# Solve for Center of Rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rotations

Consider a situation (as shown in attached image), Points D and F moving on a 2-D plane in a circular trajectory with center A. After certain time t, the points D, F moved to points E and G respectively. Angle DAE and FAG is equal. At the same time, Point B moves to point H (opposite direction with same center of rotation A). Assume I have the coordinates of D and F from point B, also E and G coordinates from points H. Note: All the points have the center A.

How do I solve for the coordinates of center A either from B and H.

[image: center of rotation]

The problem presented above is simplified in 2D.
I'm trying to use the least square approach presented in [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5841/fede358e86e060cb4bc1b286eacb4db31aaf.pdf), to estimate  the center of rotation. But in the above approach the observer is static (i.e. points B and H are same), When I include the movement of the points B (to H) the approach didn't converge to right result.

modified equation ::  \begin{equation} \label{eqn1}
C  = \sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left[\left({\mathbf{v}}_{k}^{p}- \mathbf{m}_k\right)^2 - {\left({r}^p\right)}^2\right]^2 \end{equation}

where ${\mathbf{v}}_{k}^{p}$ is the $p^{th}$ vector in the $k^{th}$ time
instance, center of rotation in $k^{th}$ instance $m_k$; and the radius of 
the sphere marked out by the $p^{th}$ vector is $r^p$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thanks @josé... Sure I'll edit the post with more details..